# Pandas: quick way to tabulate True / False in a DF column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am looking for a clever way to tabulate True / False values on DF column.

Suppose we have the following example:

```
    Array = np.array([[87, 70],[52, 47],[44, 97],[79, 36]])
    df_test = pd.DataFrame(Array, columns=['A', 'B'],index=[['Joe', 'Steve', 'Wes', 'Jim']])
```

If I want to know the number of person whose variable A is higher than 53

```
df_test["A"]>53
Joe       True
Steve    False
Wes      False
Jim       True
Name: Apple, dtype: bool
```

I am looking for a smart way to get the total number of True / False without selecting the data in the DF. In R it would be the table() function. The result would look like:

```
True: 2
False: 2
```

Does someone have an idea ?

Answer (score 2):

Here you go:

```
df_test.groupby(df_test['A']>53)['A'].count()
```

will return this:

```
A
False    2
True     2
Name: A, dtype: int64
```